# How to search and replace a value in a particular column in unix

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix, aix

I am working on a shell script in AIX which has some code to update certain values in a text file. 
The file is the format as shown below:

```
# cat $FILE
instance1   13  16
instance2   14  12
instance4   58  76
instance15  44  91
instance102 31  10
instance112 12  38
```

I am trying to search by instance name and replace the values in column 2 and column 3 with new values
I was able to do it using perl as follows:

```
# for i in `cat $FILE|awk '{print $1}'`;do 
# perl -pi -e "s/`grep -i $i $FILE|awk '{print $2}'`/$NEW_VAL_2/ if /$i/" $FILE

# perl -pi -e "s/`grep -i $i $FILE|awk '{print $3}'`/$NEW_VAL_3/ if /$i/" $FILE
# done
```

This worked but then I realized that it is replacing every occurrence of the value. For example, in the last row it is replacing the value in column 2 but also the last two characters of the instance name.

```
Example:

    # i = instance112
    # NEW_VAL_2 = 99
    # perl -pi -e "s/`grep -i $i $FILE|awk '{print $2}'`/$NEW_VAL_2/ if /$i/" $FILE

    Output:

        instance199 99  38
```

How can I search for the row by instance name and replace only the values in a particular column?

Answer (score 0):

In awk;

```
awk -v newval="$NEW_VAL_2" -v i="$i" '
  BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
  $1 == i { $2 = newval } 1' $FILE > newfile
```

---

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more about `-v` and why it's better than trying to insert variables in the middle of a script string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl one-liner solution. It is easier and faster to use pure perl here (with pattern matching) than a mixture of grep, awk and perl.

```
$ export FILE=foo

$ cat $FILE
instance1       13      16
instance2       14      12
instance4       58      76
instance15      44      91
instance102     31      10
instance112     12      38

$ export i=instance112
$ export NEW_VAL_2=99
$ export NEW_VAL_3=11

$ perl -lne 'if ( m{ \A $ENV{i} \t }xms ) { $_ = join "\t", @ENV{ qw( i NEW_VAL_2 NEW_VAL_3 ) }; } print; ' foo
instance1       13      16
instance2       14      12
instance4       58      76
instance15      44      91
instance102     31      10
instance112     99      11
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `ITEM` be the instance line to be modified.  Let `NV2` and `NV3` be the new values of the 2nd and 3rd fields.

Here's an example:

```
ITEM=instance102; NV2=100; NV3=80; sed -E -e "s/^${ITEM}(\\s+)(\\S+)(\\s+)(\\S+)(\\s*)\$/${ITEM}\\1${NV2}\\3${NV3}\\5/" $FILE
```

It also preserves the original spacing characters: be it tab, space, orcombination of tabs and spaces.  It keeps original spacing even when different spacing styles are used for different lines.